# Como pongo que un trigger me detecte cual campo se esta actualizando?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo este codigo:

```
delimiter $$ 
create trigger empleadosmodif
  before update
  on empleados
  for each row
 begin
  if updating(id_empleado) then
   insert into controlcambios values(0,'superusuario-jose',now(),old.id_empleado,new.id_empleado);
  end if;
  if updating(nombre) then
   insert into controlCambios values(0,'superusuario-jose',now(),old.nombre,new.nombre);
  end if;
  if updating(direccion) then
   insert into controlCambios values(0,'superusuario-jose',now(),old.direccion,new.direccion);
  end if;
  if updating(ocupacion) then
   insert into controlCambios values(0,'superusuario-jose',now(),old.ocupacion,new.ocupacion);
  end if;
 end $$
;
```

Comment: Y este código funciona o que es lo que hace?

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.